Deducing templated struct in template functions parameters
Consider the following code:
template <typename RetType, typename ResultFlagType>
struct Ret
{
    RetType         value;
    ResultFlagType  flag;

    operator        RetType()           { return value; }
    operator        ResultFlagType()    { return flag; }
};

template <typename T>
struct StructType
{
    T       a;
    float   b;
    char    c;
};



enum class ResultFlag
{
    Success,
    Failure,
};

template <typename T>
Ret<StructType<T>, ResultFlag> BuildStruct(T a, float b, char c)
{
    return { { a, b, c }, ResultFlag::Success };
}

template <typename T>
Ret<StructType<T>, ResultFlag> ModifyStruct(StructType<T> s)
{
    s.b += 3;
    return { s, ResultFlag::Success };
}



int main()
{
    auto ret = BuildStruct(3, 2.1, 'a');
    if (ret == ResultFlag::Success)
    {
        ModifyStruct(ret);
    }
}

In the current form, the compiler (GCC in this case) will fail the deduction/substitution step complaining that "Ret<StructType<int>, ResultFlag>' is not derived from 'StructType<T>"
Let's say we're not allowed to change main(), ModifyStruct(), or struct StructType, is there a way to instruct the compiler to correctly deduce, or cast, ret to the proper type automatically for us?
The only way I found so fa is to explicitly cast to the correct type when passing ret to ModifyStruct:
if (ret == ResultFlag::Success)
{
    ModifyStruct((StructType<int>)ret); // Don't mind the C-Style cast.
}


You can use static_cast instead of a C style cast to make it a bit nicer. But apart from that - casting is the proper way to use operator  RetType() and get RetType from Ret.

Not sure how this answers the issue or is relevant to the question at all: avoid the explicit casting is the point of the question.

It's not an answer (and not posted as one). Just a comment that casting seems OK to me.

Casting, if done explicitly, is pointless in this context. Ret is a struct, fields are public.

Your problem is that template deduction happens before conversions are considered in overload resolution, so T can't be deduced. This is one of the reasons that implicit conversion operators are not a great idea.
Not sure if this counts as "changing" ModifyStruct, but you can add an overload
template <typename T>
Ret<StructType<T>, ResultFlag> ModifyStruct(Ret<StructType<T>, ResultFlag> ret)
{
    return ModifyStruct(ret.value);
}


I thought about writing an overload, but I was hoping to be able to just write something similar to a deduction guide. I guess this will have to do. Thanks!

Template argument deduction does consider implicit conversions. Though you can make the conversion explicit.
You can deduce T from Ret<StructType<T>, ResultFlag> via a trait
template <typename T> struct get_T;
template <typename T,typename U> struct get_T<Ret<StructType<T>,U>> { using type = T; };
template <typename T> using get_T_t = typename get_T<T>::type;

And write an overload that performs the cast:
auto ModifyStruct(auto s) { 
    return ModifyStruct(
        static_cast<StructType<get_T_t<decltype(s)>>>(s)
    );
}

Live Demo
PS: I first misunderstood the code and was on a completely wrong track. After I removed the unnecessary parts from my overly complicated solution the above was left over. This answer achieves the same in a simpler way.
